# Broken pipe error with Google App Engine

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I'm getting a broken pipe error with gae/python, and none of the solutions I can find seem to apply to my case. (For example, the question below is similar, but it hinges on the use of submit vs button which is not my issue).

[Google App Engine & jQuery Ajax causes a Broken Pipe error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4878523/google-app-engine-jquery-ajax-causes-a-broken-pipe-error)

Here's my javascript:

```
var testVar = [1,2]

function testFun() {
    jQuery.post("http://localhost:8084",testVar.toString(), function()
    {
        console.log( "post ok" );
    }
)
document.write(testVar)
}
```

Here's the HTML:

```
<!doctype html>

<html>

<head>
<title>Experiment</title>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<style type="text/css">  </style>
<script type="text/javascript" src="lib/jquery/jquery-1.4.2.js"></script>
<script src="js/posttestjs.js"></script>

</head>

<body>

<input id = "start_button" type="button" onclick= "testFun()" value="begin"> 

</body>

</html>
```

And here's my python:

```
from google.appengine.ext import db
import webapp2
import logging

class data(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def post(self):
        logging.info('CHECK1')
        self.response.out.write("""<html><body> CHECK2 </body></html>""")


app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([('/', data)] , debug = True)
```

The error I get is this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/SocketServer.py", line     284, in _handle_request_noblock
    self.process_request(request, client_address)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/SocketServer.py", line     310, in process_request
    self.finish_request(request, client_address)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/SocketServer.py", line     323, in finish_request
    self.RequestHandlerClass(request, client_address, self)
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-        default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/dev_appserver.py", line     2630, in __init__
BaseHTTPServer.BaseHTTPRequestHandler.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/SocketServer.py", line 640, in __init__
    self.finish()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/SocketServer.py", line     693, in finish
    self.wfile.flush()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/socket.py", line 303, in     flush
    self._sock.sendall(view[write_offset:write_offset+buffer_size])
error: [Errno 32] Broken pipe
```

Last, here's my .yaml file:

```
application: posttestjs
version: 1
runtime: python27
api_version: 1
threadsafe: true

handlers:
- url: /static
  static_dir: static
- url: /.*
  script: posttestjs.app
```

I see CHECK1 in the log, so I think that the post is received OK, but the response doesn't work.

In case it's relevant: I'm using firefox, and python 2.7.3. Thanks!

Comment: local development? all the time or just occasionally?

Comment: a lot of revelvant stuff here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/180095/how-to-handle-a-broken-pipe-sigpipe-in-python

Comment: Yes - local, development. And it does happen all the time; it's never worked correctly.

Comment: And thanks for the link, but my feeling is that the error shouldn't be happening in first place.

Comment: What's calling the `testFun()` function?

Comment: A button does that: <input id = "start_button" type="button" onclick= "testFun()" value="begin">

Comment: And is that button in a form? It would be better if you posted the full template.

Comment: No, it's not in a form. I've put all the HTML in an edit above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Oddly, the issue went away as soon as I started putting the posted data into the GAE datastore. I don't see any good reason why this should have fixed the problem, but it seems to have done so.

Answer (score 0):

Looking over a working example of mine (one that works on dev_appserver), I note two things. Here's what I do (slightly simplified):

```
jQuery.post("/", {'key': 47}, function(response) {
   ...
});
```

First, I don't pass an explicit port. In your case, unless you're running dev_appserver with `--port 8084`, you're not going to connect.

Second, I'm passing a dict, where you're passing a list. http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/ doesn't say that passing a list works.

Comment: Dave, thanks for the suggestions. A few things: first, I'm doing everything locally, so I know what port is being used. I tried using "/" as in your example, but I got the same error. I also tried some other things -  e.g. /static - with the appropriate modifications to the python, but no luck there either. As for your other point, I tried posting a string (as in the edited code above), and a dictionary, but I get the error for these as well. Also, I see CHECK1 in the log, so it seems that at least the incoming part of the post works.

Answer (score -1):

As far as I can tell this is a comment:

```
self.response.out.write("""<html><body> CHECK2 </body></html>""")
```

Those should be single quotes.

Comment: Nope. Triple-quotes are for multi-line strings. If the first statement in a function is a string, it serves as the method doc.

Comment: From the stack trace it looks like the problem is in the response somehow.  If that's not it, maybe he needs to set the response header.  Try self.response.headers['Content-Type'] = 'text/plain' first.